# what is the error description for a mapping exception?

Tags: exception, mapping

Error Name            Error Description
Mapping Exception.     what can I use to describe a mapping exception?

Error Name            Error Description
Mapping Exception.     Mapping does not conform to the expected standards
Mapping Exception.     Incorrect mapping information